# How to make predictions from LSTM and plot it using python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I am still a beginner at using **LSTM** to make **forecasting time series** data.
I have successfully made that model using **LSTM** from time series to make forecasting using this tutorial:

https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-analysis-visualization-forecasting-with-lstm-77a905180eba

now what I want is to use that model to :

1. predict the new values
2. and plot these values using `matplotlib`
   so for example :

if I want the values of the next 4 days then get it and plot on the curve.
I have searched a lot for that but no result found
below are the model code and the curve I have drawn
thanks

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=70, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), 
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10)], verbose=1, shuffle=False)

model.summary()

train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
# invert predictions
train_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(train_predict)
Y_train = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_train])
test_predict = scaler.inverse_transform(test_predict)
Y_test = scaler.inverse_transform([Y_test])
print('Train Mean Absolute Error:', mean_absolute_error(Y_train[0], train_predict[:,0]))
print('Train Root Mean Squared Error:',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_train[0], train_predict[:,0])))
print('Test Mean Absolute Error:', mean_absolute_error(Y_test[0], test_predict[:,0]))
print('Test Root Mean Squared Error:',np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_test[0], test_predict[:,0])))
```

then for plotting results(when I want to continue the curve to make predictions for the next time period)

```
aa=[x for x in range(200)]
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.plot(aa, Y_test[0][:200], marker='.', label="actual")
plt.plot(aa, test_predict[:,0][:200], 'r', label="prediction")
# plt.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=True) #remove ticks
plt.tight_layout()
sns.despine(top=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.07)
plt.ylabel('Global_active_power', size=15)
plt.xlabel('Time step', size=30)
plt.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.show();
```

[image: prediction]

Comment: Your question is ambigious. You already made predictions and plotted the data. What is it exactly that you want which is different than what you did so far?

Comment: for example, I predict depending on 4 steps back, so if today is the last day in the data containing the true value of gmv, I want to predict tomorrow's value, and then when tomorrow comes then predict the day after tomorrow and so on.@rocketsfallonrocketfalls